# SESN0008E when login in ibm/console at the same time with login in application

Tags: websphere, ltpa

**Environment**: WebSphere AS 9.0.0.10.

I am trying to log in in my app(http://myhost:9080/myapp/login.xhtml), that deployed at WAS and next log in WAS administrative console(https://myhost:9043/ibm/console).
After a successful log in my app in the next browser tab, I try to log in to the administrative console by another user. It returns me 500 HTTP code and in logs:

```
SESN0008E: A user authenticated as anonymous has attempted to access a session owned by user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/CN=dv,OU=Users,OU=S,DC=c,DC=s,DC=u.                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
SESN0008E: A user authenticated as user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/uid=uadm,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm has attempted to access a session owned by user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/CCN=dv,OU=Users,OU=S,DC=c,DC=s,DC=u.
```

I guess that is somehow connected with LTPA tokens. As my application and administrative console are in one host, they have a single "LtpaToken2" cookie. When I log in my app I get LTPA for user "dv" and when I log in in ibm/console I get LTPA for user "uadm", that LTPA replaces "LtpaToken2" cookie. If I return the previous "LtpaToken2" cookie by manual, I can open the administrative console again, but in an attempt to log in I get a new LTPA and 500 HTTP code.
I tried to disable "Security integration" on the server, but it didn't give anything.

**AuthFilter**

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        WebUser user = (WebUser) session.getAttribute(Constants.webuser);
        Principal principal = req.getUserPrincipal();

        String jUserLogin = req.getParameter(Constants.jUserLogin);
        String jUserPassword = req.getParameter(Constants.jUserPassword);

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(jUserLogin)) {
            loginBean.setjUserLogin(jUserLogin);
            byte[] loginBytes = (jUserLogin + ":" + jUserPassword).getBytes();
            String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(loginBytes);
            session.setAttribute(Constants.userLogin, encoded);
        }

            if (user == null && principal != null) {
                user = new WebUser();
                loginUser(req, session, user, principal);
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private void loginUser(HttpServletRequest req, HttpSession session, WebUser user, Principal principal) {
        WebUser oldUser = (WebUser) session.getAttribute(Constants.webuser);
        user.clean();
        user.setLogin(principal.getName());
        user.setPass(session.getAttribute(Constants.userLogin));
        session.setAttribute(Constants.webuser, user);

    }
```

**login.xhtml**

```
            <form action="j_security_check" method="POST">
                <p:panel styleClass="login-panel block_center" header="LoGIn" style="width:400px;">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="no_border_panel_grid" columnClasses="panel_grid_column_250px" style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
                        <p:inputText id="j_username" placeholder="Login"/>
                        <p:password id="j_password" placeholder="Pass"/>
                        <input id="my_button_5" type="submit"
                               style="width: 77%; margin: 0; padding: 9px; margin-top: 10px" value="Log in"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </form>
```

**What wrong with it? I have no idea(**

Comment: are you saying it works if you remove the `p:panel`, `p:panelGrid` and replace the inputs with plain html ones?

Comment: no, it didn't help

Comment: So the question is in no way JSF related then... You (we) narrowed things down a little more. Good luck